# C# How to create a collection of generic class which derives from a specific implementation of another generic class which is a derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract

Struggling with wording that title to make any sense so I will just show my code and try and explain it

So I have this base class

```
public abstract class SpacecraftProperty
{
}

public abstract class SpacecraftProperty<T> : SpacecraftProperty
    where T : SpacecraftProperty<T>
{
    public abstract void Add(T property);
}
```

With this I can create a collection of `SpacecraftProperty` just fine thanks to the base `SpacecraftProperty` class that is not generic.

Then I have this class that derives from `SpacecraftProperty` that is also generic

```
public class ResourceStorage<ResourceType> : SpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<ResourceType>>
    where ResourceType : ResourceInfo, new()
{
    public ResourceType resource { get; private set; } = new ResourceType();
    public float        capacity { get; private set; }
    
    public override void Add(ResourceStorage<ResourceType> property)
    {
        this.capacity += property.capacity;
    }
}
```

Now the issus is that I need to create a collection of this `ResourceStorage` class, where each object in the collection can be of any type for `ResourceType`. But I can't use the same trick as above where I create a non-generic base class as then when I try and derive from `SpacecraftProperty<>`, it won't know what type of the generic `SpacecraftProperty` to derive from.

For completeness, here is the code for `ResourceInfo`, which is an `abstract class` which will be derived from

```
public abstract class ResourceInfo
{
    public abstract string GetName();
    public abstract string GetDescription();    
}
```

So in summary I would for example want a collection that contains say a `ResourceStorage<SomeTypeA>`, `ResourceStorage<SomeTypeB>` etc. where `SomeTypeA` and `SomeTypeB` derive from `ResourceInfo`. And `ResourceStorage` derives from `SpacecraftProperty`, which has the generic method `Add`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use "normal" type-names for generic-type parameters. I was thrown-off entirely by your use of `ResourceType`  in `ResourceStorage<ResourceType>` - methinks you should change that to just `T`. The convention in C# is to use very short names for type-parameters and often with "`T`" as a prefix.

Comment: Also, `where T : new()` is a code-smell (because any nontrivial type with a parameterless constructor can't possibly initialize itself into a valid state without any kind of initial data - so consider removing the `new()` constraint and instead accepting a `Func<T> itemFactory` argument instead, that allows your consumers to use constructors properly.

Comment: @Dai The new() constraint is required though so the ResourceStorage class can create a new ResourceType (or just T when I change it) object. The ResourceInfo is trivial so can have a default constructor. 


edit: missed the part of your comment about passing a factory to construct the ResourceInfo - I will have a go a that

Comment: The only real way is to abandon compiler time type safety and delegate to runtime. That is, inspect if each object is of the righ type and call `Add()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't use the same trick as above where I create a non-generic base class as then when I try and derive from `SpacecraftProperty<>`, it won't know what type of the generic `SpacecraftProperty` to derive from.

You can use the same trick. The type to derive from is `SpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage>`, where `ResourceStorage` is the non-generic type you have created. This is because the implementation of `Add` in the generic `ResourceStorage<T>` doesn't actually use `T`.

```
// note that I've changed the naming conventions to match that of C#'s
public abstract class ResourceStorage: SpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage> {
    public abstract float Capacity { get; protected set; }
}

public class ResourceStorage<TResource> : ResourceStorage
    where TResource: ResourceInfo, new()
{
    public TResource Resource { get; private set; } = new TResource();
    public override float Capacity { get; protected set; }
    
    public override void Add(ResourceStorage property)
    {
        Capacity += property.Capacity;
    }
}
```

`ResourceStorage<TResource>` is now a `SpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage>`, however, and not a `SpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<TResource>>`.

To fix that, you can make the abstract classes contravariant interfaces instead. Since there is only one `Add` method:

```
public interface ISpacecraftProperty {}

public interface ISpacecraftProperty<in T> : ISpacecraftProperty
    where T : ISpacecraftProperty<T>
{
    void Add(T property);
}

public interface IResourceStorage: ISpacecraftProperty<IResourceStorage> {
    public float Capacity { get; }
}

public class ResourceStorage<TResource> : IResourceStorage
    where TResource: ResourceInfo, new()
{
    public TResource Resource { get; private set; } = new TResource();
    public float Capacity { get; private set; }
    
    public void Add(IResourceStorage property)
    {
        Capacity += property.Capacity;
    }
}
```

Now this compiles:

```
var list = new List<IResourceStorage>() {
    new ResourceStorage<Foo>(),
    new ResourceStorage<Bar>()
};
// This'd work too, but I'm sure you are aware already, since it is the nature of what you are trying to do
list[0].Add(list[1]);

ISpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<Foo>> x = new ResourceStorage<Foo>();
```

If `ISpacecraftProperty` has other methods that return a `T`, and so can't be contravariant, you can always just add `ISpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<TResource>>` as yet another interface of `ResourceStorage<TResource>`.

```
public class ResourceStorage<TResource> : IResourceStorage, ISpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<TResource>>
    where TResource: ResourceInfo, new()
{
    public TResource Resource { get; private set; } = new TResource();
    public float Capacity { get; private set; }
    
    public void Add(IResourceStorage property)
    {
        Capacity += property.Capacity;
    }
     
    // implement explicitly by delegation   
    void ISpacecraftProperty<ResourceStorage<TResource>>.Add(ResourceStorage<TResource> property) {
        Add(property);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought interfaces might be the way to go but wasn't sure. thanks I'll give this a go

Comment: @user2758663 Note that by doing this, you would be able to do things like `new ResourceStorage<Foo>().Add(new ResourceStorage<Bar>())`, unless you add a runtime check for the type of `property` in `Add`. I'm curious on what your thoughts on being able to do that is. Did you want to be able to do this from the very start? Or did you not expect to be able to do this but think it's a nice behaviour to have? Or do you not like it at all?

Comment: one more thing, how can I adapt this to work so I can use the Add() function on objects of ISpacecraftProperty. So if I have a ISpacecraftProperty a, and ISpacecraftProperty b - and both of these are actually of the type ResourceStorage<ResourceTypeA> and I want to call a.Add(b) and it call the Add() function in ResourceStorage<T>. In this scenario I would know what the type is (e.g. ResourceStorage<T>) - some kind of casting?

Comment: @user2758663 I guess you are talking about the non-generic `ISpacecraftProperty` here? Well, you know more than the compiler here, so you can only cast. If you know they are actually `ResourceStorage<ResourceTypeA>`, why don't you store them in varibales of that type in the first place?

Comment: The type is not known at compile time, but will be at runtime. At compile time, all that is known is that it derives from ISpacecraftProperty. The properties are stored in a dictionary with a Type key, so when I want to add a property, it looks up the type in the dictionary, then if it exists it Adds() to that one, rather than inserting a new one into the dicitonary. As it's looking up Type, if it is found then it is known that both the existin property and the new one have the same type - but at compile time all that's known is that it is ISpacecraftProperty

Comment: @user2758663 Oh okay, that sounds like a totally different question than what you what you originally posted. I suppose the problem of creating a collection of `ResourceStorage<Anything>` was an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)? If *that's* how you are actually going to use these types, there is no point in fiddling with generics, since they are a *compile-time* type safety thing. Anyway, I'd suggest that you post a new question about that if you are still having trouble.

Comment: I figured it out. I just added an Add(ISpacecraftProperty property) method to the ISpaceProperty interface - then implement that in the ResourceStorage class to call the more specific Add() method

Comment: Yeah all a bit confusing but figure it out now. Basically I have a collection of ISpacecraftPropery's which is all of my properties for a spacecraft. I then have a separate collection of just the ResourceStorage properties - which is why I need to be able to put them in a collection.

Comment: For ResourceStorage<T>, T can't be anything - has to be a ResourceInfo